# How To Have A Rig In The Same Scene Twice

Tags: rigging

I downloaded a rig of the internet, and want to know how to duplicate the rig in the same scene so I can have two in one file.
Is it possible? The rig is Z Animation rig.

Comment: please dont write the title or description in all caps

Comment: your keyboard its broken or something?

Comment: [All uppercase letters is perceived as  shouting](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41249/when-did-people-decide-that-all-caps-means-the-writer-is-shouting)   Like making a Scene at a [Seance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9ance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select the armature in object mode , press <kbd>a</kbd> and then press <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> and drag and click to move